# How can I unpack (destructure) elements from a vector?

Tags: rust, vector

I am currently doing the following:

```
let line_parts = line.split_whitespace().take(3).collect::<Vec<&str>>();
let ip = line_parts[0];
let bytes = line_parts[1];
let int_number = line_parts[2];
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
let [ip, bytes, int_number] = line.split_whitespace().take(3).collect();
```

I'm noticed various references to vector destructuring on some sites but the official docs don't seem to mention it.

Comment: Personally I’d use `let mut parts = line.split_whitespace();` followed by `let (ip, bytes, int_number) = (parts.next().unwrap(), parts.next().unwrap(), parts.next().unwrap());` or more likely `if let (Some(ip), Some(bytes), Some(int_number)) = (parts.next(), parts.next(), parts.next())`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It seems what you need is "slice patterns":

```
fn main() {
    let line = "127.0.0.1 1000 what!?";
    let v = line.split_whitespace().take(3).collect::<Vec<&str>>();

    if let [ip, port, msg] = &v[..] {
         println!("{}:{} says '{}'", ip, port, msg);
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=044975c92af9c86096045f88f78cd266)

Note the `if let` instead of plain `let`. Slice patterns are *refutable*, so we need to take this into account (you may want to have an `else` branch, too).

Comment: Answer made in 2015, seems slice patterns went stable in Rust 1.26 ([link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/slice-patterns.html)). Very nice, though does make the else case of the irrefutable pattern a bit of a pain with multiple bindings...

Answer (score 10):

You can also use this:

```rust
use std::convert::TryFrom;

let v = line.split_whitespace().take(3).collect::<Vec<&str>>();
let [ip, bytes, int_number] = <[&str; 3]>::try_from(v).ok().unwrap();
```

The return type of `<[&str; 3]>::try_from(v)` will be the [`Result` type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/) which you can use for error handling or allow it to panic as I did, since we already know that the size is 3.