# Result getting unexpected type argument

Tags: rust

I am attempting to read values from a file in order to create a struct, and I'm getting a weird pair of errors. A super basic implementation of my code:

```rust
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Itertools;
use std::io::{self, prelude::*, BufReader};
use std::fs::{self, File};

// The struct I will unpack into
struct BasicExample {
    a: String,
    b: String,
    c: String,
    d: String,
}

impl BasicExample {
    pub fn new(a: String, b: String, c: String, d: String} -> Self {
        BasicExample {
            a, b, c, d
        }
    }

    // I'm expecting that reading from the config file might fail, so
    // I want to return a Result that can be unwrapped. Otherwise an Err
    // will be returned with contained value being &'static str
    pub fn from_config(filename: &str) -> io::Result<Self, &'static str> {
        let file = File::open(filename).expect("Could not open file");

        // read args into a Vec<String>, consuming file
        let args: Vec<String> = read_config(file);

        // I transfer ownership away from args here
        let params: Option<(String, String, String, String)> = args.drain(0..4).tuples().next();

        // Then I want to match and return, I could probably do if-let here
        // but I don't have my hands around the base concept yet, so I'll 
        // leave that for later
        match params {
            Some((a, b, c, d)) => Ok(BasicExample::new(a, b, c, d)),
            _ => Err("Could not read values into struct")
        }
    }

    fn read_config(file: File) -> Vec<String> {
        let buf = BufReader::new(file);

        buf.lines()
            .map(|l| l.expect("Could not parse line"))
            .collect()
    }
}
```

Running `cargo check` to make sure I didn't miss anything, I get the following error:

```sh
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 2
  --> src/lib.rs:37:60
   |
37 |     pub fn from_config(filename: &str) -> io::Result<Self, &'static str> {
   |                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ unexpected type argument

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0107`.
```

Seems a bit odd. `io::Result` should take `<T, E>`, and I've given it `E`, so let's remove that type argument and see what happens:

```sh
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:54:22
   |
54 |             _ => Err("Could not read values into AzureAuthentication struct"),
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::io::Error`, found reference
   |
   = note: expected type `std::io::Error`
              found type `&'static str`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

For some reason it is really not happy with the `E` I provided. I'm a complete beginner with rust, so maybe I'm just not sure what I'm looking at. What am I doing wrong here? The `itertools` ownership trick was borrowed (ha) from [this wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43658017/7867968).

### System Details:

- macOS 10.13.6
- rustc 1.36.0 (a53f9df32 2019-07-03)
- cargo 1.36.0 (c4fcfb725 2019-05-15)

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation of [`std::io::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/type.Result.html)? You will find that it actually takes only a single type parameter.

Comment: Oh! You're completely right, it's not the same as `Result`, hence "Expected io::Error"

Comment: i like the way they gave different things the same name

Comment: @guesty they did, but they didn't. The module `std::io` means that the name `Result` is safe from shadowing, I just wasn't paying attention. In my code, I even noted `io::Result`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually a super basic error, but one that looks arcane until you get to know (and love) `std::io`.

In short, `std::result::Result` (the result you know) !== `std::io::Result`. The documentation for the first is [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html), while the second is [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html)

You'll notice on the second one that it is actually a type alias to `Result<T, std::io::Error>`. What this means is that it is effectively shorthand for that, where your error case is an instance of `std::io::Error`.

As a result, your code is incorrect when you are attempting to just `Err()` it with a string slice (since the slice is not `std::io::Error`, evidently).

There are multiple ways to fix this:

- You can convert your entire error chain to another type (explicitly or by taking advantage of `into()` casts)
- You can make your own errors return `std::io::Error` instances

There are valid cases for both options, which is why I'm mentioning both. The second is done relatively easily, like so (full paths are there for documentation purposes). Suppose you're returning an error which matches an entity not found. You would be able to do it like so:

```
`Err(std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::NotFound, "Could not read values into AzureAuthentication struct"))`
```

There is, however, a better way for your function:

```
pub fn from_config(filename: &str) -> io::Result<Self> {
    let file = File::open(filename)?;
    let args: Vec<String> = read_config(file); // This has no error possibility

    let params: Option<(String, String, String, String)> = args.drain(0..4).tuples().next();
    params.ok_or(std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::NotFound, "Could not read values into struct")).map(|(a, b, c, d)| BasicExample::new(a,b,c,d))
}
```

This removes all the indirection from your method and neatly folds away the error types, one by one, so you don't have to worry about them. The `Option` gets turned into a `Result` thanks to `ok_or`, and all is well in the best of worlds :-)

Comment: Fantastic. Yeah, looking back, I'm also just *moving* the ownership problem to `params`, which cannot be passed to the `BasicExample` constructor anyways, because it's still an Option<borrowed `String`>. Time to go back to The Book and error handling :)

Comment: We've all started somewhere. The key is to learn and improve, although error handling can be difficult to get right the first time. I know I'm guilty of having created balls of spaghetti before on that very topic :-)

Answer (score 7):

A common pattern in Rust is if your module uses a lot of `Result<T, ModuleSpecificErrorType>`, then you can make a custom `Result<T>` that abstracts out the error type. This custom type has one fewer generic parameter because the error type is hardcoded.

A `std::io::Result<T>` is an abstraction over `std::result:Result<T, std::io::Error>`.

See [the documentation for `io::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html).

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Made the mistake of thinking `io::Result` is the same as `Result`, which it's not