# What does Result<()> without the error type mean?

Tags: rust, rust-result

I was looking at the [`std::env::current_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_dir.html) documentation and this caught my attention:

```rust
std::io::Result<()>
```

I thought a `Result` should have a `T` and an `E`. How can you substitute them with `()`?

Comment: That's a [`std::io::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html), not a `std::result::Result`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Result getting unexpected type argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57794849/result-getting-unexpected-type-argument)

Comment: Thanks @SCappella, both your link and Brian's answer are helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::io::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html) is a type alias specific to the `std::io` module, which is defined as

```
type Result<T> = Result<T, ::std::io::Error>;
```

Essentially, it's a `std::result::Result` with the error type prefilled as a `std::io::Error`. Using this type only requires one type parameter, which corresponds to the "ok" type `T` in `Result<T,E>`.